# Angular Directive: After adding a directive I no longer see data from ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

How would I get the data from email address or password?  In my case I have a combo box with an ng-model="selectedObject" assigned to it.  However in my controller, $scope.selectedObject does not contain any data.  It doesn't seem to be bound.  Also, this binding worked before I added the directive.  Any ideas?

```
<modal title="Remove a Group" visible="showRemoveModal">
  <form name="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div style="width:500px">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="Name">Name&nbsp;</label>
         <select ng-model="selectedGroupForDelete" ng-options="group.Name for group in groups" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="deleteGroup()" ng-disabled="!selectedGroupForDelete">Remove</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</modal>
```

Here is the link to a sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/

Comment: You need to include some code in your question and not just in an external location. Be sure to [check out the help center for how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And welcome!

Comment: Thanks!  Added my code that is similar to the jsfiddle to be more precise with what I am doing.

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap have you considered using AngularUI? It has it's own modal directive that makes working with them fairly easy and straightforward without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I've been running into cross stack version issues with bootstrap and angular.  I cringe when thinking about adding more, but looking at the docs, it does look like it has what I need.  Thanks!  I'll look into this.

Comment: you cant get bind ng-value to a scope directly. How nice the fiddle have botstrap loaded too.